# Bash corrupted echo for heredoc

Tags: bash, sh, echo, heredoc

Here my script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -r -d '' content << VAR
one
two
three
{"foo":"bar"}
{cron":"0 1 * * *"}
VAR

for line in $content; do
  echo "==| ${line}"
done
```

without line `{cron":"0 1 * * *"}` it works perfectly and produces correct output:

```sh
==| one
==| two
==| three
==| {"foo":"bar"}
```

but with line `{cron":"0 1 * * *"}` it prints corrupted output:

```sh
==| one
==| two
==| three
==| {"foo":"bar"}
==| {cron":"0
==| 1
==| LICENSE
==| README.md
==| ed
==| y.sh
==| LICENSE
==| README.md
==| ed
==| y.sh
==| *"}
```

I'm running this script on `macOS`.

Comment: Why have a seperate `read` command and `for` loop instead of a single `while read` loop with a here document? See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The correct way is to use a while-loop instead of a for-loop. See other answers.

The "for line"-loop splits at whitespace. The first unwanted whitespace is the space in cron line between "0" and "1". The "junk" in the output are the script's command line arguments? At least my tests look like they are.

To avoid splitting at whitespace, use the variable IFS. Set it to "newline".

```
IFS=$'\n'
read -r -d '' content << VAR
one
two
three
{"foo":"bar"}
{"cron":"0 1 * * *"}
VAR
for line in $content; do
  echo "==| ${line}"
done
```

Comment: There's minimal splitting involved here, because `read` is only given one target. The only "splitting" would involve removing any leading or trailing whitespace. The problem is with the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited my post. The "IFS=" can acually be set right before the "for line"

Comment: That doesn't stop `*` from expanding.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write this script is a `while` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done <<'EOF'
one
two
three
{"foo":"bar"}
{cron":"0 1 * * *"}
EOF
```

At the very least, you don't need `read` to set the value of `content`:

```
content='one
two
three
{"foo":"bar"}
{cron":"0 1 * * *"}'
```

but iterating over a file using a `for` loop is full of problems. See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)